# Issue importing flask_cors module into Flask App

Tags: python, flask, pip

Hello I am running an application with Flask and have installed flask-cors as per the documentation, however when I try to import the module into my app.py file I get this error:

```
from flask_cors import CORS
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_cors'
```

Anyone know what may be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run in console following command:

```
pip install flask_cors
```

or in some case

```
pip3 install flask_cors
```

And be sure that you running Python 3 instead of Python 2